# Divide http response to header and body by content-length

Tags: http

Is good idea to split http response to header and body with content-length value? Is it safe? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish? The body is separated from the header by two line breaks if I'm not mistaken. If this is how it is defined in the spec this is how I would find the body. This tutorial contains a lot of good information about the composition of an HTTP message, http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, its not. the http secification is based on linebreaks: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4

or read this: [Separating HTTP Response Body from Header in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551898/separating-http-response-body-from-header-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good idea. The content-length is how you know where the end of the content is, not the other way around. You shouldn't assume the end of the content and work backwards by the content-length to the beginning of the content. In some cases, the content-length is the only way you know where the end of the content is. In modern HTTP, the server does not close the connection at the end of the response by default, and might be sending more than one response on the same connection if you made more than one request. The only way to know where one response ends and the next begins is the content-length. If you assumed you'd read until the connection closes and then work backwards to the start of the content, you might find the middle of the content or part of an entirely different response instead.